# Extracting a part of a sparse matrix is extremely slow

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

A is a Matlab sparse matrix. Under some circumstances the following code snippet is really slow:

```
fprintf('\nTest. ')
tic
A_cut = A(entry_range, entry_range);
toc
asize = size(A) 
anonzero = nnz(A)
nonzero = nnz(A_cut)
entries = numel(entry_range) * numel(entry_range)
```

Looking at the output, there seems to be no obvious reason for a deviation of 11 seconds for a equivalent operation. What could cause such differences? And how to speed up the extraction?

Output:

```
Test. Elapsed time is 0.013671 seconds.
asize =
      816968      816968
anonzero =
       57646
nonzero =
       17036
entries =
   7.3291e+09

Test. Elapsed time is 1.190594 seconds.
asize =
      816968      816968
anonzero =
       57646
nonzero =
    22
entries =
   217916644

Test. Elapsed time is 11.440432 seconds.
asize =
      816968      816968
anonzero =
       57646
nonzero =
     0
entries =
   2.0938e+09
```

Comment: What is `entry_range`? Please provide initialisations for all variables. I guess it's slow because the third iteration hit's a segment without zeros.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not getting out of virtual memory and having to write at swap? What is the type of A_cut, is also sparse?